# AutoMapper and .NET Core: Profile is not effective

Tags: .net-core, automapper

In an ASP.NET Core application I have a profile class (for AutoMapper) like this:

```
 public class CandidateProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public CandidateProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Job.Candidate, Job.Candidate>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Id, y => y.UseDestinationValue());
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs I registerAutoMapper with DI like this:

```
 services.AddAutoMapper(c =>
        {
            c.AddProfile<JobProfile>();
            c.AddProfile<CandidateProfile>();
            c.AddProfile<ApplicationProfile>();
        }
```

My aim is to not change the value of the Id property in the destination object. However the destination Id always gets set to 0 which is the value of the source object.

```
existingCandidate = _mapper.Map(app.Candidate, existingCandidate);
```

After calling this code, existingCandidate.Id is 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried with your scenario in console app, it didnt work well, I see automapper initialize the destination type while mapping. So I found a work around, may not be the good solution but can solve your problem. Use `mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source, opt => opt.BeforeMap((src, dest) => { src.id = destination.id; }))`.  [Check this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vyux1G)

Answer (score 0):

> My aim is to not change the value of the Id property in the
> destination object.

So, basically for `Id`, you don't want the source property to be mapped to the destination property. You want it left alone. Simply `Ignore` the mapping for that property then -

```cs
CreateMap<Candidate, Candidate>()
.ForMember(x => x.Id, y => y.Ignore());
```

**Edit :**
Following is the code that is working for me with above configuration (version 10.0) -

```cs
public void Test()
{
    Candidate appCandidate = new Candidate { Id = 0, Name = "alice" };
    Candidate existingCandidate = new Candidate { Id = 4, Name = "bob" };

    existingCandidate = _Mapper.Map(appCandidate, existingCandidate);
}
```

Comment: I tried .Ignore() too but the same thing happens. The value of Id is overwritten (set to 0)